# Kotlin Stream.asSequence() now requiring Stream.iterator().asSequence()

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using java.net.HttpClient to issue a simple GET request where the response is of type HttpResponse<Stream>.  However, even though Kotlin.streams has an [asSequence() method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/as-sequence.html), I now have to first convert the stream to an iterator before calling asSequence(). Why is this the case?

```
val client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().let { builder ->
    builder.uri(URI("http://localhost:8000/response.txt"))
    builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    builder.GET()
    builder.build()
  }
val resp: HttpResponse<Stream<String>> = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines())
  //used to be resp.body().asSequence().map{
  resp.body().iterator().asSequence().map {
    println("${it.toString()}")
  }
```

Comment: A couple immediate guesses: you need to import the extension function, or it's not actually a java.util.stream.Stream but some other thing named Stream, or you're using a version of Kotlin without that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build.gradle.kts I was referencing the wrong version of the jdk.  The problem resolved when I imported `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` as a dependency.